# fontspec: No autofakebold when given boldfont

Tags: macros, fontspec, bold

I am writing a latex macro.

I know that `\defaultfontfeatures{AutoFakeBold=4}` can open fake bold in fontspec

but this will use fake bold if or not `BoldFont` is given

I want a function like:

```
if no BoldFont of mainfont:
    \defaultfontfeatures{AutoFakeBold=4}{mainfont}
```

how to write this? Thanks!

Comment: Imho AutoFakeBold is something that should be used on a font by font basis and not by default.

Comment: Also many font when loaded by font name have a (non-fake) bold font even if no `BoldFont` is explicitly given, so `BoldFont` is not a good indicator for this.